# how to convert latitude/longitude to pixels in 3d using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, openlayers

I have lat/lon of a portion of a map. I want to put the point of this lat/lon in 3d space webgl(lib: three.js). Then how to convert lat/lon to corresponding x,y,z cords.

Comment: What are you asking here? It sounds like you want us to define your coordinate space for you; we don't know what is practical, so we can't make those decisions for you. Give us more details about what you have to work with (screen size, depth, size of map portion within the GL coordinate system, etc.)

Comment: there are so many algorithms for this. what have you tried?

Comment: I have a set of lat/lon and altitude which corresponds to an image taken from map.  It is actually an image of uneven surface. If surface has hills then its has its lat/lon and alt is very high and vice versa. how to represent those lat/lon alt in 3d world(as x/y and z).e.g lat=17.1234 lon=83.1234 alt=23 to what x?,y?z(=alt)?

Answer (score 1):

Because latitude and longitude are pieces of 2D-representation, you need to choose which plane will be used for the projection. The most simple one will be: X - longitude, and Y - latitude. Second do scaling if you need some precise location. But it is the most simple case as I've already said. In general the map projection is a lot more complex. See for example the answers here [lat/lon conversion to x/y-coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513122/lat-lon-conversion-to-x-y-coordinates). Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Spent a bit of time searching for the best "three.js way" to solve this. Figured I'd include it here for posterity's sake. Following assumes Y is up:

```
const latLngToVector3 = (latLng, radius) => {
  const phi = Math.PI * (0.5 - (latLng.lat / 180));
  const theta = Math.PI * (latLng.lng / 180);
  const spherical = THREE.Spherical(radius || latLng.radius || 1, phi, theta);
  return new THREE.Vector3().setFromSpherical(spherical);
};

const vector3ToLatLng = (v3) => {
  const spherical = new THREE.Spherical().setFromVector3(v3);
  return {
    lat: 180 * (0.5 - (spherical.phi / Math.PI)),
    lng: 180 * (spherical.theta / Math.PI),
  };
};

// convert to x,y,z with radius = 1
const v3 = latLngToVector3({ lat: -16.8985, lng: 145.7134 });

// convert back to lat/lng
const latLng = vector3ToLatLng(v3);
```

Check out the [Spherical.setFromvector3](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Spherical.js) and [Vector3.setFromSpherical](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Vector3.js) methods to see the inner workings here.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new point with pixels, it converts to lat an lng.

```
var offsetX = 10;
var offsetY = 10;
var mapZoom = 5;
var point = new google.maps.Point(
     offsetX / Math.pow(2, mapZoom),
     offsetY / Math.pow(2, mapZoom)
);
```

And after this you can just sum point.x and point.y with another point.